# Hierarchical query - limiting number of elements per level

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchy

I am working with an Oracle DBMS and I have a question regarding hierarchical queries.

I am creating an org list for my department at work with the use of a hierarchical SQL query. There are three levels to the org structure which are, in order, department manager, section manager, and team member.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT level, employee_number, name, manager, department, phone
FROM employee_table
START WITH manager is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_number = manager;
```

This query produces a hierarchical list in which the department manager is at level one, each of the section managers is at level two, and the team members are at level three. Overall, there is only one department manager, three section managers, and 30 team members.

The problem: My requirement is to limit the number of employees at each level in the list to a maximum of three employees. This is no problem for the first two levels since there is only one department manager and three section managers (there will never be more than three section managers), but I currently have 30 team members at level three (each section manager manages 10 team members). My goal is to have three team members at level 3, three team members at level 4, three team members at level 5, etc. The order of the team members doesn't matter, so it doesn't matter which team members are at level 3, which team members are at level 4, etc.

I would prefer to avoid setting the manager of a team member be the employee_number of another team member just to achieve this goal. I could just create another column in the employee_table called something like "org_list_parent" and indicate that the "org_list_parent" of one team member is the employee_number of another team member, but I would prefer to avoid doing that as well, if possible.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this problem?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Using mathguy's query, I was able to get the closest output to what I was trying to achieve. However, there is something I would like to tweak about the output, if possible. I am using this list to build an Org Chart in Oracle Apex, and with mathguy's table and query, I get the following output:

[image]

This is very close to the visual I am trying to produce. The reason behind the "3 team members per level" is to try to prevent the chart from being excessively large horizontally. However, if you look to the left, for example, Employees 1104, 1105, and 1106 are underneath 1103 and employee 1107 is underneath 1106. It would be best if employee 1104 were underneath 1101, employee 1105 underneath 1102, employee 1106 underneath 1103, and employee 1107 underneath 1104. Is there any way to edit the query so that it produces that result visually?

**Update 2:**

alexgibbs requested feedback on the two different queries he suggested as solutions for my problem. The following is his first query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEVEL < 3
          THEN LEVEL
        ELSE 3 + FLOOR((DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MANAGER ORDER BY 
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ASC ) - 1) / 3) END AS ADJUSTED_LEVEL,
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
START WITH MANAGER IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = MANAGER
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1 ASC;
```

And the following is the output for this query as a list in Oracle Apex:

[image]

The following is his second query:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN LEVEL < 3
 THEN LEVEL
 ELSE 3 + FLOOR((DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MANAGER ORDER BY 
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ASC ) - 1) / 3) END AS ADJUSTED_LEVEL,
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
MANAGER,
DEPARTMENT
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
START WITH MANAGER IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = MANAGER
ORDER BY
NVL2(MANAGER,1,0) ASC,
DEPARTMENT ASC,
CASE WHEN LEVEL < 3
 THEN LEVEL
 ELSE (MOD((DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MANAGER ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 
ASC )) - 1,3) + 3) END ASC,
ADJUSTED_LEVEL ASC;
```

And the following is the output for this query in Oracle Apex:

[image]

Comment: A "hierarchical query", in the absence of `LEVEL` and other such calculated things in the `SELECT` list, is nothing but an *ordering* of rows, depth first. Do you care about that order? Other than that, in your `SELECT` list you just have `LEVEL` - is that the only thing you need to change? Also: When you say only three employees per level, do you mean over ALL rows, or only "three employees at the same level FOR EACH MANAGER" (so a total of nine employees at each level overall)?

Comment: Three employees at the same level for each manager, so a total of nine employees at each level overall. I don't fully understand your first two questions, but essentially what I am looking for is the single department manager at level 1, the 3 section managers at level 2 (the order of the section managers does not matter), 9 team members at level 3 (3 for each section manager), 9 team members at level 4, etc. It doesn't matter which team members are at which level (3, 4, etc), but the parent of the team members in level 3 need to be their respective section manager in level 2.

Comment: Thanks Katherine.  What would you want to happen if a fourth section manager were added?

Comment: That's a good question, @alexgibbs, and while I do not anticipate it ever happening, I suppose it is possible. In that case I would prefer that the fourth section manager to be at level two with the other section managers, and then have 12 team members in each row below level two (three team members for each of the four section managers). Regardless of the number of section managers in level 2, I will always want three team members for each section manager in levels 3, 4, 5, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks Katherine.  I'll proceed along those lines.

Comment: What I mean by "hierarchical order" (in the output) is that the Big Boss is on the first line; the first mid-level manager is on the second line, followed by all of that manager's subordinates; then the second mid-level manager with all his subordinates, and then the third manager with all her subordinates. Do you need your query result to follow this order? For example, the query already written in an answer does NOT follow that order (and indeed, it's not that simple to get the right order AND the levels as you want them; it is still relatively simple, but not **that** simple).

Comment: Regarding the edit (update): There is nothing in my answer that has 1104, 1105 and 1106 reassigned to 1003 as manager; that is **entirely** on the ApEx side. I don't know ApEx at all, but since it is responsible for that graphical representation, I don't know how anything I do differently in my query will be reflected in ApEx. You should add the ApEx tag at the bottom of the question and hope that ApEx experts will be able to help.

Comment: @mathguy, that makes sense. Thank you very much for all your help. I will research the issue from an Apex perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do this.

First the test data (I included enough employees to illustrate the point, but not quite 10 employees for each mid-level manager). I left out the phone number as irrelevant to the problem at hand.

```
create table employee_table(employee_number, name, manager, department) as
    select 1001, 'Big Boss', null, 100 from dual union all
    select 1100, 'Beth Mgr', 1001, 100 from dual union all
    select 1101, 'Jim'     , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1102, 'Jackie'  , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1103, 'Helen'   , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1104, 'Tom'     , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1105, 'Vance'   , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1106, 'Rosa'    , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1107, 'Chuck'   , 1100, 100 from dual union all
    select 1200, 'Duck Mgr', 1001, 200 from dual union all
    select 1201, 'Danny'   , 1200, 200 from dual union all
    select 1202, 'Henry'   , 1200, 200 from dual union all
    select 1203, 'Mac'     , 1200, 200 from dual union all
    select 1204, 'Hassan'  , 1200, 200 from dual union all
    select 1205, 'Ann'     , 1200, 200 from dual union all
    select 1300, 'Adam Mgr', 1001, 300 from dual union all
    select 1301, 'Wendy'   , 1300, 300 from dual
;
```

Then the query. I want the output to follow the "hierarchical order" (as it would be if we didn't have to mess with the levels). For that, I run the hierarchical query first, I capture `ROWNUM` for ordering of the final results, and I modify the level in the outer query. Note that I use `LVL` as column name; `LEVEL` is a reserved word, so it should not be used as column name.

```
select   case lvl when 3 then lvl + ceil(rn/3) - 1 else lvl end as lvl,
         employee_number, name, manager, department
from     (
          select     level as lvl, employee_number, name, manager, department,
                     rownum as ord, 
                     row_number() over 
                        (partition by manager order by employee_number) as rn
          from       employee_table
          start with manager is null
          connect by prior employee_number = manager
         )
order by ord
;
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
       LVL EMPLOYEE_NUMBER NAME        MANAGER DEPARTMENT
---------- --------------- -------- ---------- ----------
         1            1001 Big Boss                   100
         2            1100 Beth Mgr       1001        100
         3            1101 Jim            1100        100
         3            1102 Jackie         1100        100
         3            1103 Helen          1100        100
         4            1104 Tom            1100        100
         4            1105 Vance          1100        100
         4            1106 Rosa           1100        100
         5            1107 Chuck          1100        100
         2            1200 Duck Mgr       1001        200
         3            1201 Danny          1200        200
         3            1202 Henry          1200        200
         3            1203 Mac            1200        200
         4            1204 Hassan         1200        200
         4            1205 Ann            1200        200
         2            1300 Adam Mgr       1001        300
         3            1301 Wendy          1300        300
```

Comment: You bring up a good point, but I'm not sure yet which query will produce the exact output I am looking for. I need to spend some time tonight and tomorrow testing both queries with my data. I thank you for the work you put into this, and I will definitely return and comment with a more definitive response after I test your query. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yep, no problem - adapt to your needs and come back if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: please look at my update in the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This has been edited significantly in response to an update in the question, and is uncertain/not-tested with apex for compatability**

The below solution would just add section managers beyond the third at level 2.  But for level 3+, if it does not matter how additional levels are assigned beyond the section managers, one can just assign them based on `employee_id`.  With the update that each member of a group-of-three should have their pseudo-next-level nested directly below, here is an example that assigns pseudo-levels and sub-levels in groups of three, based on employee id, within a department.

Below is an example data set and query.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_TABLE (
  EMPLOYEE_NUMBER NUMBER,
  MANAGER NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  NAME CHARACTER VARYING(64 BYTE),
  DEPARTMENT CHARACTER VARYING(64 BYTE),
  PHONE CHARACTER VARYING(64 BYTE)
);


--Dept Manager
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (10,NULL, 1);
--Section Managers
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (200,10, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (300,10, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (400,10, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (500,10, 5);
-- Section Employees
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2010,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2020,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2030,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2040,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2050,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2060,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2070,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2080,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2090,200, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2100,200, 2);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3010,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3020,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3030,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3040,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3050,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3060,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3070,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3080,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3090,300, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3100,300, 3);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4010,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4020,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4030,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4040,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4050,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4060,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4070,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4080,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4090,400, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (4100,400, 4);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5010,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5020,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5030,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5040,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5050,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5060,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5070,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5080,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5090,500, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (5100,500, 5);
COMMIT;
```

**Edited** 
Query:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN LEVEL < 3
     THEN LEVEL
     ELSE 3 + FLOOR((DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MANAGER ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ASC ) - 1) / 3) END AS ADJUSTED_LEVEL,
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
MANAGER,
DEPARTMENT
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
START WITH MANAGER IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = MANAGER
ORDER BY
NVL2(MANAGER,1,0) ASC,
DEPARTMENT ASC,
CASE WHEN LEVEL < 3
     THEN LEVEL
     ELSE (MOD((DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MANAGER ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ASC )) - 1,3) + 3) END ASC,
ADJUSTED_LEVEL ASC;
```

Result:

```
  ADJUSTED_LEVEL   EMPLOYEE_NUMBER   MANAGER DEPARTMENT
               1                10           1
               2               200        10 2
               3              2010       200 2
               4              2040       200 2
               5              2070       200 2
               6              2100       200 2
               3              2020       200 2
               4              2050       200 2
               5              2080       200 2
               3              2030       200 2
               4              2060       200 2
               5              2090       200 2
               2               300        10 3
               3              3010       300 3
               4              3040       300 3
               5              3070       300 3
               6              3100       300 3
               3              3020       300 3
               4              3050       300 3
               5              3080       300 3
               3              3030       300 3
               4              3060       300 3
               5              3090       300 3
               2               400        10 4
               3              4010       400 4
               4              4040       400 4
               5              4070       400 4
               6              4100       400 4
               3              4020       400 4
               4              4050       400 4
               5              4080       400 4
               3              4030       400 4
               4              4060       400 4
               5              4090       400 4
               2               500        10 5
               3              5010       500 5
               4              5040       500 5
               5              5070       500 5
               6              5100       500 5
               3              5020       500 5
               4              5050       500 5
               5              5080       500 5
               3              5030       500 5
               4              5060       500 5
               5              5090       500 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed and quick solution, @alexgibbs. I will spend time tonight and tomorrow testing your query with my dataset to ensure that it produces the exact output I am looking for, and then I will return to comment with a more definitive response to your solution. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks Katherine.  I would echo @mathguy - if any follow up would be helpful just let me know.  Meantime, I believe mathguy's solution has a nicer, cleaner layout and a natural sort; I would recommend that solution.

Comment: please look at my update to the original question :)

Comment: Thanks Katherine.  I don't use apex, so I can't make a confident update here.  I'll add a provisional edit that just re-assigns and re-sorts, but apologies in advance it may not be what you are looking for.  I would also defer largely to @mathguy  as your update uses data from mathguy's answer.  Nonetheless I'll update now with a best guess.

Comment: Ok @KatherineReed updates made.  I'd appreciate any feedback whether this gets at the kind of layout you were looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: I posted some feedback to your queries as an update to the original question. Unfortunately, neither query produced exactly what I was looking for in terms of the output in Apex, but I think mathguy is right in that I need to look for the solution in Apex. Thank you very much for all your help!